# Array​.filter unexpected result when using Number function as filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just found this problem when use Array​.prototype​.filter(), someone can explain to me why?

I have these two arrays

```
[0, NaN, NaN, NaN]

[1, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

When I call filter() using `Number` type filter the return of first is an empty array with instead the second return is an array.

I think the check on `0` as a `Number` fail but why? I tried to construct a `Number` with `0` and it work obviously.

```js
console.log([0, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(Number)); // []

console.log([1, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(Number)); // [1]

// other examples
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].filter(Number)); // [1, 2, 3]

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(Number)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4].filter(Number)); // [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

console.log([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4].filter(Number)); // [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]

console.log([-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(Number)); // [-1, -2, -3, -4]
```

Thank you in advance guys and girls.

Comment: `Number(0)` returns `0` which is falsey. Why would you expect that to just pass? `Number` doesn't return boolean values, after all.

Comment: "*When I call filter() using `Number` type filter*" wait, that's not a *type* filter at all. You should probably re-check the documentation on [what `filter` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - it expects a *predicate*, and `Number` is not one.

Comment: The `Number()` function doesn't tell you whether something is a number, it converts it to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

`0` & `NaN` are both **falsey** values, hence, they are removed by the filter function.

To filter in 0, you can use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) like following

```js
console.log([0, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(v => !isNaN(v))); // [0]
```

Comment: Also as side note it's better to use `Number.isNaN()` - `isNaN('x')` is true, because it first convert it string to number.

Comment: If this is duplicate why it has 7 answers ;(

Comment: @jcubic - Thank you for your input and I totally agree with you. However, as the scope of question was lying around numeric values and NaN, i opted in for `isNaN`.

Answer (score 2):

If the return value from the `filter` callback is falsey, the resulting item will not be included in the resulting array. Because 0 is falsey, just like NaN is falsey, it does not get included.

Non-zero, non-NaN numbers like 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3 are not falsey, so they *do* get included.

To filter out `NaN` values, consider using `Number.isNaN` instead:

```js
console.log([0, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([1, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
console.log([-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(item => !Number.isNaN(item)));
```

If you want to make sure that the item is a number too, then check `typeof` as well:

```js
const callback = item => typeof item === 'number' && !Number.isNaN(item);

console.log([0, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(callback));
console.log([1, NaN, NaN, NaN].filter(callback));
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].filter(callback));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(callback));
console.log([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4].filter(callback));
console.log([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4].filter(callback));
console.log([-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(callback));
```

Comment: If OP expects a filter for numbers, then I guess you also need to check `typeof item === "number"`, otherwise stuff like `"1"` would not be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` is  falsy

It will only work on Truthy values.

you can about truthy values here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 1):

It's because of something called 'falsey'. you pass Filter a function, and if that function returns false, or a falsey value, for a particular item in the array, that doesn't get returned in the final array.

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed to [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is supposed to return true or false. `Number(0)` produces the number 0 which is coerced to false, which explains why you get `[]` as the result.

Answer (score 1):

`Number` coverts the argument to the number data type, so it is like a null-operation on your actual sample data: they already are of type number. Filter will only retain truthy values, and both 0 and NaN are not truthy.

What you could use instead is:

```
.filter(Number.isFinite)
```

This will exclude NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, and data that is not of numeric data type, but will keep all finite numbers.

If you need other data types (e.g. a string like "23") to be converted to number *and* retained after the filter, then chain:

```
.map(Number).filter(Number.isFinite)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the filter function you enter a condition, the result of number(0) is 0 and 0 is a negative condition (like NaN), on the other hand Number(1) is 1 or Number(0.1) is 0.1 which give rise to a positive condition.

Examples:

```
[-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(()=>0.1);  // [ -1, -2, -3, -4 ]
[-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(()=>0));   // []
[-1, -2, -3, -4].filter(()=>NaN);  // []
```